# Can i still get to the old files once i transfer a cPanel account to another server

Tags: domain, files, domain-transferring

I've recently transfered a cPanel account to a new host and now i'm curious as to how i can access the files on the old server.

I used to login to the cpanel of the old server with cpanel.mywebsite.com and now when i do that, it goes to the cpanel of my new host. Is there any way to get to the cpanel of my old host?

Comment: This really isn't a sysadmin issue.  Surely you remember the old IP address you had before you adjusted your DNS.  Or maybe you can simply contact the support for your old webhost.

Comment: I know this is shutting the barn door after the horse has bolted... but didn't you consider this scenario in your planning?

Comment: This was my first domain transfer and i completely forgot about the email addresses.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is "No".

If you really need access to the files you'll need to contact your old hosting provider.

The old files still exist (or will for a while), but aren't accessible via the domain (obviously). You'll need either to create a temporary domain to access your old files or use a sub-domain from the old provider.

If this isn't possible they might ftp the files to you (but don't hold your breath).

Do this quickly because they might wipe your files and assign the disk space to someone else.

Answer (score 1):

It may be possible **if you happen to know the IP address** that was assigned by the previous provider.  Just use the IP in place of the host name in the URL.  However, it's unlikely that they will keep your files online for long after your service agreement ends.

You could also try the [WayBack Machine](http://www.waybackmachine.org/) as they keep an archive of all publicly accessible sites indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

The hosting provider has access to the files for as long as the cPanel account on the old server has not been [terminated](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/TerminateAccount) or the content hasn't otherwise been manually deleted.

When a cPanel account is [copied to another server](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/CopyAccount#About%20streaming%20transfers), the content remains on the old server, but the [cPanel account is suspended](http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/11_30/WHMDocs/SuspendUnsuspend).  The hosting provider has the option of terminating the cPanel account on the old server at any time.

This is one of the easier way to reclaim the space that your account previously occupied.  So, others who offered an answer about this are correct that you should contact your old provider as quickly as possible.